# An example of geometrically integral projective surface that is not smooth

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X \subseteq \mathbb{P}^n$ be a geometrically integral projective surface of degree $d$ defined over $\mathbb{Q}$. Does it then imply that $X$ is smooth? I was wondering if someone could provide me with a counter example. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $n\geq 3$ with homogeneous coordinates $x_i, 0\leq i\leq n$ and take the quadric $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2=0$. It is geometrically integral, but has a singular point, $(1,0,\ldots,0)$.